# How to use async function with set interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

```
async function getContent(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const content =  await page.content();
    await console.log(content);
    await browser.close();
}

setInterval(searchTarget(), 13000);
```

I have this async function that gets content from a webpage using puppeteer. I want to be able to check the web page every so often, so I tried to use setinterval but I kept getting errors. Any ideas?

Comment: "I kept getting errors" - **what errors**?

Comment: My advice: Don't use setInterval. Call the function again in the resolve with a timeout

Comment: You've posted a function called `getContent` but you're **passing the result of a function-call** (not the function itself) named `searchTarget` to `setInterval`.

Comment: Also you need to not have () in an interval or timeout call `setInterval(searchTarget, 13000);`

Answer (score 5):

- You've posted the definition of `getContent`, not `searchTarget`.
- You're passing **the result** of `searchTarget` to `setInterval` rather than passing a reference to the function `searchTarget`.
- You say you're getting errors but haven't said what those errors are.
- You **can** use an `async function` with `setInterval`.
- You don't need to use `await` with `console.log` (you shouldn't use `await` because  as `console.log` doesn't return anything, let alone a `Promise<T>`).

I assume what you actually want is this:

```
async function getContent() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const content =  await page.content();
    console.log(content);
    await browser.close();
}

const timerId = window.setInterval( getContent, 13 * 1000 );

// You can call `window.clearInterval( timerId )` to stop the interval loop.
```

---

I recommend adding error-handling that stops the interval loop on the first error:

```
/** @type {number} */
let intervalTimerId = null;

async function getContent() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        const content =  await page.content();
        await console.log(content);
        await browser.close();
    }
    catch( err ) {
        console.error( "Error in getContent: %o", err );
        if( intervalTimerId ) {
            window.clearInterval( intervalTimerId );
        }
    }
}

intervalTimerId = window.setInterval( getContent, 13 * 1000 );
```

#### Alternative approach:

As other users like @mplungjan and @RohanAsokan have pointed out, there are potential design issues with your code because `setInterval` will call `getContent` every 13 seconds even if the previous call to `getContent` still hasn't finished yet - this could happen if (for example) `await page.content()` took longer than 13 seconds to run.

In which case the solution is to use `window.setTimeout` instead of `window.setInterval` and to call it from within `getContent`, like so:

```
/** @type {number} */
let lastSetTimeoutId = null;

async function getContentAndStartLoop() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        const content =  await page.content();
        console.log(content);
        await browser.close();

        lastSetTimeoutId = window.setTimeout( getContentAndStartLoop, 13 * 1000 );
    }
    catch( err ) {
        console.error( "Error in getContent: %o", err );
    }
}
```

Note that `getContentAndStartLoop` will resolve after the first loop but keep on running itself until an error is thrown.

#### Better approach:

I think it'd be better to structure it like so (using a `Promise`-adapter for `setTimeout` named `delay`):

```
async function myProgram() {
    
    const url     = "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/":
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page    = await browser.newPage();
    
    try {
        while( true ) {
        
            await page.goto( url );
        
            const content = await page.content();
            console.log( content );

            await delay( 13 * 1000 );
        }
    }
    catch( err ) {
        console.error( "Error in myProgram: %o", err );
    }
    finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
    
}

async function delay( ms, state = null ) {
    
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        window.setTimeout( () => resolve( state ), ms );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will ask you a question and you will have your answer.

What do you think will happen if the `async` request to `getContent()` takes more time than the `13000` millisecond interval?

Hence a better option would be to resolve the promise and call the function again as suggested by @mplungjan in the comments.

A possible but unclean solution would be to clear the interval if a previous promise has not been resolved.

Comment: how would i go about resolving the promise and calling the function? ( I am veeeery new to promises)

Comment: @b0b75 You don't need to manually "resolve" any promises - that's handled for you by the `await` operator. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: @Dai I can't comment on your post. But just to point out, by repeatedly calling the function and setting it in a infinite call stack, you are loosing out on the optimization advantages given by `setInterval`. @b0b75 also look into this.

Comment: @RohanAsokan "by repeatedly calling the function and setting it in a infinite call stack" - please explain what you mean by this. I don't believe there is a potential for a stack-overflow in the code I posted. If there's a problem with my code please post a comment reply to my answer with more details.

Comment: @RohanAsokan Also, *what* "optimization advantages" are you referring to?

Comment: AFAIK it does not push on to the call stack. As in the stack size won't increase with using it, though it increases the load on the CPU, it is light on memory. If that makes sense?

Comment: @rohanAsokan Neither does `setTimeout` nor the use of `Promise`. Anyway, worrying about the stack-size in JS is almost entirely unnecessary - either your code causes an infinite recursion and stack-overflow or it doesn’t. Remember that because JS doesn’t have explicit stack allocation (unlike C) the only way a non-buggy script would overflow was if the data structure it was traversing was ridiculously huge; which won’t happen in practice (because if it was that big you wouldn’t be using JS in the first place)